# "It was the first time I did" or "It was the first time I do"?

Tags: past-tense

I did something in the past. Now, when I mention it to others, should I say:

> It was the first time I **did** that.

or:

> It was the first time I **do** that.

Which part of English grammar should I have a look to understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be totally correct, you should actually say,

> It was the first time I **had done** ____

which is the *past perfect* tense. However, you may also hear the simple past used, which is the first of your sentences.